# rexexp or preg_match. Which one should I use?

Tags: php, regex

I'm wanting to use regular expressions to extract letters and numbers from a string but I'm very novice with regular expressions and wanted to ask if I should use rexexp or preg_match

Comment: `preg_match` is a built-in php function. Not sure what you mean with `rexexp`.

Comment: Commonly we use preg_match :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). "rexexp" is probably just a misspelled version of "regexp", an abbreviation for "regular expressions".

Comment: Hi Marius, My mistake on the typo. Sheesh... There's no getting anything past ya'll but what's the difference and which is better?

Comment: @StuartY You're comparing apples to pears: "regexp" just refers to the concept of regular expressions in general, whereas `preg_match` is a specific function implemented in the [PCRE regex engine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php).

Answer (score 0):

preg_match is commonly use, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php for details about preg_match

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the scope of your system, but I would recommend [strpos](https://www.php.net/strpos) if you're only looking to do a few small operations. From the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for preg_match (Just above the comments):

> "Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is
> contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they
> will be faster."

Comment: Will, Thanks for sharing. Unfortunately strpos won't work since it's coming from UI which translates to: "I never know where in the string the letters and numbers may appear"